# как посчитать количество символов внутри кавычек?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день! Пишу небольшой скрипт по выявлению зловредов на сайте, уже выявил некоторые закономерности... Какой регуляркой можно подсчитать общее количество символов, находящихся внутри всех кавычек в тексте?

Comment: Это надо делать не регуляркой, так как регулярные выражения не умею считать ;)

Comment: Какие символы относите к кавычкам? Вложенные кавычки как считаете? Добавьте примеры текста, в котором посчитать.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = '"in quotes" not in quotes "123""test"';
$e = explode('"', $text);
$result = array();
$s = sizeof($e);
for ($i = $sum = 0; $i < $s; ++$i) {
    if ($e[$i] === '') { continue; }
    if($i % 2 != 0) {
        //Для удаления пробелов, если нужно, конечно
        $e[$i] = str_replace(' ','', $e[$i]); 
        $sum += mb_strlen($e[$i]);
    }
}
var_dump($sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант покороче

```
$str = 'Строка с "набором" слов, заключённых в "кавычки".';
preg_match_all('~(?<=")\S+(?=")~', $str, $a);

echo mb_strlen(join($a[0]), 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: в очереди проверок попался Ваш ответ. Вы можете посмотреть, что было изменено, и увидеть, что именно в коде ничего не поменялось

Answer (score 0):

Используйте этот код:

```
$text = "текст с 'рядом' кавычек в 'формате' UTF-8";
$count = 0;
// ищем текст в кавычках
preg_match_all('/\'([^\']+)\'/u', $text, $matches);
// если текст найден, то считаем в цикле количество символов
if (isset($matches[1])) foreach($matches[1] as $str) {
    $count += mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Для текста в ASCII-кодировке надо убрать в регулярном выражении флаг `u` и использовать просто `strlen`. Если вы имели ввиду другие виды кавычек (не одинарные), то подставьте в регулярном выражении нужный вам тип.

Comment: а зачем вам цикл? Можно же воспользоваться count().

Comment: @Эдуард count посчитает количество найденных отрывков текста, на не само количество символов в нем.